# How to retrieve the first item in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am new to javascript. I am doing a task which trying to get the first item removed from an array in javascript.

Method One

```
  function getFirst(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  var removed = arr.shift();
  return removed; 
}
```

Method Two

```
function getFirst2(arr, item) {
  arr = arr.push(item);
  var removed = arr.shift();
  return removed;
}
```

I comes out with these two solution but only method one accepted and method two is the wrong one which return Uncaught TypeError: arr.shift is not a function().

What is the extacly meaning of Uncaught TypeError and state that arr.shift is not a function but it works on Method one?

Any help will be appreciate! Thanks!

Comment: I did not actually understand your question. What are you trying to achieve? `shift()` is returning first item.
Also `push()` makes no sense here. Please provide a more descriptive question

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the return value of [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). You are reassigning `arr` to a value that isn't an array, so `shift()` fails because it does not exist for that other value.

Comment: @AlexBykov Hi, the task require to write a function which take an array and a number as arguments. And add the number to the end of the array then remove the first item of array. And the function should return the item that was removed. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @4castle Thanks! Finally understand what wrong with my code!

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getFirst2()` is not working because of `arr = arr.push(item)`.
Here `arr` actually becomes a number, as the push method on an array returns `the new length property of the object upon which the method was called`.

Thus calling method push on a number throws a TypeError.

Comment: Thanks! I will be careful what is the return value next time!

Answer (score 0):

Your first Method is alright. But i'd like to note that you do not always have to create a local fucntion-scope variables. Your `return` statement can return computed values. So instead of

```
 function getFirst(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  var removed = arr.shift();
  return removed; 
}
```

I would go for

```
 function getFirst(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  return arr.shift(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, you are right! The code you write is much more clean and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the shift function on an array. In method 2, arr is not an array anymore because I think that the push method returns the length of the array. This is why you are getting a typeError.
Try printing arr before applying the shift method to see what it is.

Comment: Thanks!! Finally, understand that the return value is integer and that's why throw me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has many inbuilt functions that are attached to different data types. The Array type has the functions `push(), unshift(), shift()` etc that are attached to every array but not to other non-array types. 
When you use these Array functions on any type that is not an array you get the Uncaught type error, because the Javascript interpreter cannot read the function off that type.

Your second function on this line: `arr = arr.push(item);` , changes the value of `arr` to a number because the return value of the function `arr.push(item);` is a number(Int). Hence trying to call `.shift()` on `arr` is no longer allowed because `arr` is no longer an array.

Comment: Really appreciate your helps!!